# The Mitla apartment, shouldn't it be the Mitlas'?

Tags: possessives

Stephen King writes:

> Howard Mitla was sitting alone...
> Violet Mitla, one of New York's...
> **The Mitla apartment** was on the fourth floor...

I was expecting something like "The Mitlas' apartment". Is that a typo, or is that some kind of alternative grammar structure I am not aware of?

Comment: It's a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct). I suspect this question is a duplicate, but it might belong better on English Language Learners.

Comment: @StuartF, thanks. I found this: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/283341/petrovskis-home-residence-or-petrovski-home-residence I wasn't expecting noun adjuncts with family names.

Comment: Regarding English.SE vs ELL.SE, I think you guys either need to merge the two communities or find a better way to keep them separate. As of now, the situation is confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't missing a plural or a possessive - the surname is being used as a *qualifying noun*.

For example, the family of a person named "John Smith" may be referred to as "*the Smith family*". The surname is used as a qualifying noun to modify the noun 'family'. The alternative would be to make the family name possessive and say they were  "John Smith's family".

Your example is similar - the home may belong to the Mitla family, so you could say it was "the Mitlas' apartment", but saying "the Mitla apartment" is also fine.

Comment: Just to make sure I get it right: did you mean to write "the Mitlas' apartment" instead of "the Mitla's"? Also, in "the Mitla apartment", the article refers to the apartment, right? (The + Mitla apartment).

Comment: @reed: in *the Mitla apartment*, the article refers to apartment, but in *the Mitla's apartment*, the article refers to Mitla. That doesn't make any real difference here, but you would say *Japan's market* (without an article) and *the Japan market*.

Comment: Where I live is the Harvey house.

Comment: @reed You are quite right about the plural possessive, that was a typo and I've corrected it. If you were ascribing ownership of the apartment to just one person, it would of couse be singular - "John Mitla's apartment". In the case of ascribing it to the whole family of Mitlas, use the 'apostrophe after the s' rule.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, out of curiosity, would you also say it's the Michael house? It sounds weird to me but hey, so did the Mitla apartment before I posted here.

Comment: We can use a surname as a qualifying noun for things - the Harvey house, car, family, and so on. So, no, not the Michael house, although it is, of course, Michael's house.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Unless Michael is their surname.

Comment: @Astralbee Indeed. Due to the way MS Outlook presents email senders' names, I am regularly assumed by remote colleagues to be "Harvey Michael" (they overlook the comma) and addressed "Dear Harvey". I resist the temptation to reply "Dear Robinson".